# Is it possible to connect desktop's date to microsoft excel?

Tags: excel, date, time, calendar, excel-formula

I have this incubator for chicken eggs and I want to make an excel file where I can put the details of the eggs that I put in the incubator, like date of incubation and date of hatching, so I can manage all the batch of eggs.

FYI, the incubation period of an egg is 21 days(max). After 18 days in the incubator, the eggs should be transferred to the hatchery for 3 days until they are hatched.

With that, is it possible if Microsoft Excel can connect to my computer's date to compute the number of days the eggs have been in the incubator.

Like if the start of incubation for the first batch is April 1, Microsoft Excel should compute compare computer's date to come up with April 18 as the hatching period.

What formula should I use?

Comment: Is this as simple as `=TODAY()`?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to do this!

I'd love to post a screen shot, but I don't have enough points.
anyway...

```
Cell A1 => Start Date
Cell B1 => Days to Hatch
Cell C1 => Move On
Cell D1 => Today's Date

Cell A2 => 4/1/2013
Cell B2 => 18
Cell C2 => =A2+B2-1  (subtract one to get the correct count)
Cell D2 => =today()
```

or

```
Cell A1 => Start Date
Cell B1 => Today
Cell C1 => Days Left

Cell A2 => 4/1/2013
Cell B2 => =Today()
Cell C2 => =A2+17-B2
```

you could also add conditional formatting to highlight the due date when it matches in the first example or days left in the second example.